# Access Cloudant database from multiple applications

Tags: cloudant

I would like to connect to the same database on Cloudant with different applications.  Only one of the applications is going to be writing to the database, and the other would be reading only.

Is this okay to do?

Comment: Of course you can do that. I don't see what you're concerned about. Even having multiple applications writing to the database is not a problem as long as your applications know how to handle conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! Perfectly OK.

As Kim mentioned, the only thing to worry about with multiple asynchronous connections comes from when different applications / clients try updating the same doc. When this happens, Cloudant will create a conflict, storing both updates so you can sort out which is correct.

Check out [Conflict Management in CouchDB](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html) for why this occurs and how to deal with it, and the [Cloudant docs on conflicts](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/documents.html?highlight=conflict#retrieving-conflicting-revisions) for methods to examine conflicts.